# Complete Novice: How do i get this project filter to match any word in the data-filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, var, portfolio

I'm a complete novice at Jquery, but have been trying to read up and hack at this code but I am getting nowhere.

I am stuck on this template at getting the filter to match more than one of the data filter at one time.

I am trying to get the image to be visible on both digital and responsive.

Below it is set to "digital", but is there a way to make it active on more than one data filter at one time?

I feel like if I had a bit more of a grasp of what I am missing I might be able to figure it out. Then again, it might be to complicated for a novice like myself.

Thank you for taking the time to have a look.

The site is on http://madethis.media if that is of further help.

```js
$( '.project-filters a' ).click( function(el) {
    el.preventDefault();
    var filter = $( this ).data( 'filter' );

    $( '.project-filters a' ).removeClass( 'active' );
    $( this ).addClass( 'active' );

    if( filter != 'all') {
        $( '.project' ).removeClass( 'inactive' ).not('[data-filter="' + filter + '"]' ).addClass( 'inactive' );
    }
    else {
        $( '.project' ).removeClass( 'inactive' );
    }
});
```

```css
.projects .project-filters {
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 20px 5%;
 list-style-type: none;
 border-top: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
}
.projects .project-filters > li {
 display: inline;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-size: 0.750rem;
 letter-spacing: 0.2em;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
.projects .project-filters > li + li {
 margin-left: 15px;
}
.projects .project-filters > li a {
 color: #000;
 font-weight: 700;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.projects .project-filters > li a.active {
 color: #fff;
 background-color:#feeb00;
 padding:16pt;
 
 text-shadow: 1pt 1pt #cfae18; 
}
.projects .project-filters > li a:hover {
 color: #6c6c6c;
}
.projects .project {
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.projects .project.inactive {
 opacity: 0.3;
}
.projects .project:hover {
 opacity: 1;
}
.projects .project .project-thumb img {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
.projects .project .project-overlay {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 2;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 font-size: 14px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #feeb00;
 opacity: 0;
}
.projects .project .project-overlay .project-links {
 width: 90%;
 height: 44px;
 margin: auto;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
}
.projects .project .project-overlay a {
 display: inline-block;
 height: 40px;
 width: 40px;
 margin: 0 5px;
 color: #000;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 border: 2px solid #000;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius: 50%;
}
.projects .project .project-overlay a i.fa {
 line-height: 36px;
}
.projects .project .project-overlay a:hover {
 color: #fff;
 border-color: #fff;
}
.projects .project .project-gallery {
 display: none;
}
.projects .project .project-info {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row no-gutter projects">
    <!-- Start: Filters -->
    <ul class="project-filters">
        <li><a href="#" data-filter="all" class="active" title="All">All</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter="digital" title="Digital">Digital</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter="print" title="Print">Print</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter="branding" title="Branding">Branding</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter="responsive" title="responsive">Responsive</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- End: Filters -->

    <!-- Start: Project -->
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 project" data-filter="digital">
        <div class="project-thumb"><img src="assets/img/projects/digital-responsive-1-thumb.jpg" alt=""></div>

        <!-- Project Overlay -->
        <div class="project-overlay">
            <div class="project-links">
                <a href="assets/img/projects/digital-1-jdf-a.jpg" title="JD Fitness + Nutrition" class="lightbox" data-gall="project-JDFN"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                <a href="#project-JDFN-info" data-type="inline" class="info-link"><i class="fa fa-align-left"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Project Info / Targeted by ID -->
        <div class="project-info" id="project-JDFN-info">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                        <h4 class="small-headline">Wordpress Site: <br>
                            JD Fitness + Nutrition</h4>
                        <p>The ideation was centred around existing face to face customers mirgating to the online service. <br>
                            The site is accessed in various enviroments (at home, on the go, or in the gym) by users with varying computer skills. It employs minial navigation enabling basic users to stay on course while journeying through the site.<br><br>
                            Instrustions on how Online Personal Training and its benifits are all housed under the services and prices tab, which employs a simple yet elegant touch ready sub-navigation presenting all the relevant information in bitesize chunks with virtually no scrolling needed on any device.
                        </p>

                        <h5>Skills Used</h5>
                        <p>Wordpress - HTML - CSS - Slider Revolution - Photoshop - Illustrator.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="h-spacer visible-xs-block"></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
                        <strong>Client</strong>
                        <p><img src="assets/img/projects/jdflogo_dark_tiny.png" alt="J.FD Fitness &amp; Nutrition Logo"></p>

                        <hr class="sep">

                        <strong>Project type</strong>
                        <p>Digital - Reponsive</p>

                        <hr class="sep">

                        <strong>Live link</strong>
                        <h5><a href="www.joshdavies.co.uk  " target="_blank">http://joshdavies.co.uk/</a></h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End: Project -->
```

Comment: Please learn to format your code. Its in a terrible format right now.

Comment: if you want to match any word in the data-filter attribute, why not match on just having the tag?

e.g. `div[data-filter]`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to toggle filtering and have more then one filter on projects, you can try this:

```js
var filters = [];
$( '.project-filters a' ).click( function(el) {
    el.preventDefault();
    var filter = $( this ).data( 'filter' );
    var index = filters.indexOf(filter);
    if ( index != -1 ) {
        filters.splice(index, 1);
        $( this ).removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $( this ).addClass('active');
    }

    if ( filter != 'all') {
        $( '.project' ).removeClass( 'inactive' )
            .not( '[data-filter="' + filters.join('"],[data-filter="') + '"]' )
            .addClass( 'inactive' );
    }
    else {
        $( '.project' ).removeClass( 'inactive' );
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but that didnt work the way i wanted it to. it made the the selected filter menu active colour stay active even when another filter in the menu is selected.